# Clean functional way to break out of a sequence loop

Tags: f#, functional-programming, break

I have a sequential process with an optional exit condition. One way to write the algorithms is like this

```
let mutable more = true
for slot = startSlot to endSlot do
    if more then
        more <- process()
```

The overhead of checking `more` for slots that are skipped due to an exit is insignificant. Still, it seems there should be a more elegant way to express this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recursion is usual here:

```
let rec loop slot = if slot <= endSlot && process () then loop (slot + 1)
loop startSlot
```

The compiler will reduce this to a simple loop (no *actual* recursion takes place).

Comment: +1: Tail-recursion is the way to do it in F# and it also often means you can avoid mutable variables leading to more idiomatic code.

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing this would be to use `Seq.takeWhile`

```
seq{startSlot .. endSlot} 
|> Seq.takeWhile (fun _ -> process())
|> Seq.iter ignore
```

This will exit the loop when `process()` returns `false`

Comment: `Seq` is lazy; this won't do anything unless the sequence is actually iterated.

Comment: Also `seq` is very slow compared to tail recursion/for